# Unity3D loads all the time instead of selected desktop session

Tags: 11.10, unity, login, unity-2d, desktop-environments

Every time I log out, and change session, select Unity2D and login Ubuntu is loaded, to what it seems to be in Unity3D. When I check in the terminal, that is confirmed.

I even changed the default to Unity2d, via one of the config files, but still, no joy.

It always is just Unity3D - even when I select GNOME Shell (I downloaded GNOME Shell from the software manager).

Any ideas on why Unity3D is loading instead of other desktop sessions?

Comment: ok, solved this one myself. I was clicking on 'switch user account', which seems to not notice the changing of desktop environments... you have to click log out, then click the cog wheel, make your selection, and log in....

Comment: and by the way, unity 2d is much much much faster than normal unity on old computers. It also beats gnome classic in my estimation.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Well done for find the solution.  If you come back tomorrow, please can you post an answer and you can accept it to close the question.  We can also vote on your answer as well!  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OP solved this:

> I was clicking on 'switch user account', which seems to not notice the changing of desktop environments... you have to click log out, then click the cog wheel, make your selection, and log in....